# Missing Parameter from constructor in your C# Example code

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, xero-api

I am attempting to update our C# integration oAuth2 as per Xero documentation.

I am attempting to use the sample code provided here:

https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-NetStandard/tree/oauth2/Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2Client

However, this sample code has a missing variable in the constructor: C# **IHttpClientFactory**

When I attempt to implement this sample code I get this compilation error:

*There is no argument given that responds to the formal parameter IHttpClientFactory of XeroClient.XeroClient(XeroConfiguration, IHttpClientFactory)*

Comment: Seems like this should be filed as an issue on that github repository

Comment: What versions of .NET and Visual Studio do you have installed?

Comment: If you look at the source code you can see the XeroClient takes an `IHttpClientFactory`. The README is wrong or out of date. Look at the source to see how to use it.

Comment: @juharr issue reported, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @rustyskates VS Enterprise 2017 (2). .NET Framework 4.6.1